# What has Japan done in order to prevent foreign countries from impeding their democratic election system?

Tags: united-states, japan

> In a major covert operation of the cold war, the Central Intelligence
> Agency spent millions of dollars to support the conservative party
> that dominated Japan's politics for a generation.
>
> The C.I.A. gave money to the Liberal Democratic Party and its members
> in the 1950's and the 1960's, to gather intelligence on Japan, make
> the country a bulwark against Communism in Asia and undermine the
> Japanese left, said retired intelligence officials and former
> diplomats. Since then, the C.I.A. has dropped its covert financial aid
> and focused instead on gathering inside information on Japan's party
> politics and positions in trade and treaty talks, retired intelligence
> officers said.
>
> The Liberal Democrats' 38 years of one-party governance ended last
> year when they fell from power after a series of corruption cases --
> many involving secret cash contributions. Still the largest party in
> Japan's parliament, they formed an awkward coalition in June with
> their old cold war enemies, the Socialists -- the party that the
> C.I.A.'s aid aimed in part to undermine.
>
> Though the C.I.A.'s financial role in Japanese politics has long been
> suspected by historians and journalists, the Liberal Democrats have
> always denied it existed, and the breadth and depth of the support has
> never been detailed publicly. Disclosure of the covert aid could open
> old wounds and harm the Liberal Democrats' credibility as an
> independent voice for Japanese interests. The subject of spying
> between allies has always been sensitive.

[C.I.A. Spent Millions to Support Japanese Right in 50's and 60's](https://www.nytimes.com/1994/10/09/world/cia-spent-millions-to-support-japanese-right-in-50-s-and-60-s.html?pagewanted=all&mcubz=3)

I was reading this, and I was wondering if the government took any step to prevent it from happening again - What did Japan do in order to prevent foreign countries from impeding their democratic election system? Do Japanese political party, like the LDP, still receive foreign funds?

Comment: I think Japan did next to nothing. America did something, i.e. it became politically unpalatable for intel agencies to do such stuff abroad. (Japan was also formally under US occupation 1945-52.)

Comment: As for suppression of communists etc. They were even more supressed before the US occupation.

Comment: For reasons that are actually a bit hard to explain, but inlude factionalism and general opposition from the left-wing of the political spectrum (not just communist) to restoring the levels of intelligence gathering (which went hand in hand with repression) during the pre-1945 era, post-war Japan failed to establish much of an own intelligence apparatus. For a while, the domestic spying/counter-intel had to operate under the cover of some US "historical section" and the like. Even nowadays CIRO is extremely understaffed compared to equivalents in Western countries (incl. the German BND).

Comment: There is a somewhat good account of the early years in https://www.jstor.org/stable/23419012

Comment: Are you aware that that article is from **1994**,  It is nearly 30 years out of date...

Comment: Certainly confusing to read a reference to “last year”.